# How to import test from test1.spec file to test2.spec file

Tags: javascript, cypress

The test1.spec.js have multiple tests and multiple it block, I just to import only one it block in test2.spec.js

Comment: Consider exporting the tests you want to import, and then importing them in the other test.

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you please send me the example for that

Comment: Here's a good guide on es modules https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: please give any cypress test example.

Answer (score 2):

You need a function wrapper around the test.

**Spec1**

```js
export const runTest = () => {
  it('is a test that will run when runTest is called', () => expect(1).to.eq(1))
}

runTest()  // if you want to run it here, but you can just define it here
```

**Spec2**

```js
import { runTest } from './Spec1.js'

runTest()
```

---

Also quite useful if you want to parameterize the test

```js
export const runTest = (expectedValue) => {
  it('is a test that will run when runTest is called', () => {
    expect(1).to.eq(expectedValue)
  })
}

runTest(1)  // passes
runTest(2)  // fails
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test2.spec you say:

```js
    module.exports.test2 = describe("Test 2", () => {
       // Here you put your test code using beforeAll, AfterAll, It, etc.
    });
```

In your test1.spec you say:

```js
    const test2 = require("./test2.spec");
```

Then within "describe o it" section you call test2 as a normal function, ex.:

```js
    test2();
```

Note: if you get an exception handle, just put the code where you call the function within a try/catch.

Comment: Error: test2 is not a function

Comment: Here you have another good way how to approach this:       "Simple Jasmine Tests Reuse Example · GitHub" https://gist.github.com/rinatio/5786174

Answer (score 0):

**To use a Test from another file**

Define a test as a function with direct cy. commands like:

**test2.cy.js**

```
export const test2 = () => {
    cy.get( '.abc' ).should( 'be.visible' );
    cy.get( '.abc' ).should( 'not.be.visible' );
}
```

In the other file import this test case:

**test1.cy.js**

```
import { test2 } from './test2.cy'

// Usage
it( 'Checks Something Allenish', () => {
    test2();
} );
```

Works on Cypress 12.X.X

Comment: How can you do it with a correctly-formed test? `test2.cy.js` will not run by itself, so it's not actually a test just a helper function.